# driver.get(URL), driver.navigate().to(URL), and driver.navigate().back() not working

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to grab the image URL of each laptop listing in this amazon page (https://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A565108%2Cp_72%3A4-&pf_rd_i=565108&pf_rd_p=b2e34a42-7eb2-50c2-8561-292e13c797df&pf_rd_r=E87FK4Z32CV7VPR4EZGP&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-11&pf_rd_t=BROWSE&ref=Oct_s9_apbd_otopr_hd_bw_b2N0e_S).

The method is supposed to click on each listing that is on sale, grab the image URL with driver.findElement(By.xpath(namesXpath)).getAttribute("src") and save it to the URLs list. . However, when I try to get the driver to go back to the page full of all the laptop listings so that it can continue to through the for loop and grab the images of other listings, it gives me the error below. I've tried driver.get(URL), driver.navigate().to(URL), and driver.navigate().back() but all of them fail to take me back to the previous page.

What's weird is that in my main method, driver.get("https://amazon.com") works fine and driver.findElement(by.xpath).click() works fine too. Its just in this method where it breaks.

I'm new to s=java and selenium so I hope that all made sense. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need any more clarification

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img [@id="detailImg"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-AU2FJQL', ip: '192.168.0.245', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 81.0.4044.138, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\email\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50907}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 1fe48e105aae883db4215eba6bb8c06b
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//img [@id="detailImg"]}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at Executer.picsUpdateList(Executer.java:363)
    at Executer.main(Executer.java:163)
```

```
public static String namesXpath = "//span[@data-a-strike=\"true\" or contains(@class,\"text-strike\")][.//text()]/preceding::span[@class][10]";

public static void picsUpdateList(WebDriver driver, List<String> URLs, List<BufferedImage> pics) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        //list of deals on amazon page
        List<WebElement> deals = driver.findElements(By.xpath(namesXpath));

        //URL of each picture saved since this method was called
        List<String> freshURLs = new ArrayList<String>();

        //saves the URL of the page with all listings
        String pageURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println(pageURL);

        //1. clicks on each deal from List<> deals
        //2. Grabs picture by xpath and saves the URL to both lists
        //3. 
        for(WebElement deal : deals)
        {
            deal.click();
            System.out.println("clicked on next deal");
            Thread.sleep(time);
            String url = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img [@id=\"detailImg\"]")).getAttribute("src");
            URLs.add(url);
            freshURLs.add(url);
            System.out.println(url);
/// ERROR HERE//////////////////////////
            driver.navigate().back();
//////////////////////////////////////////
            System.out.println("back to page");
            Thread.sleep(time);
        }

        for(String url : freshURLs)
        {
            pics.add(ImageIO.read(new URL(url)));
        }

    }
```

Comment: hello. just want to ask, were you able to see that the code actually did get the img src url of the first deal? was it printed out on the console/terminal (via this code System.out.println(url))?

such that the the error you've provided is not pointing to going back to the previous page but on the image src is not found.

I tried to check on the amazon deal sample online and seems like you may need a hover first on the image before the @id="detailImg" is provided in the html body of the page. so just want to know if the error is indeed in the navigating back or on getting the image source.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest using `@id="landingImage"` instead of `@id="detailImg"`.
Then get `data-old-hires` field value to get the url. This is the same as the source url you are getting from the `@id="detailImg"` (but as mentioned in my previous comment, you may need to hover first on the image in the screen before that element pops-out, which I think is the reason of the error).

You may try first on your code and let us know if this solves your issue.

Here's a sample of the deal click on the amazon page url you provided.
I've underlined in blue the details I mention above.
Hope this can solve your problem.

[image]